# Moving a magento store to a new server - 1.3.2.4 - product images do not load

Tags: php, magento

I am helping a friend move a store to a new server, but I am running into a problem at the moment. I have copied the DB and the files to the new server (since the store uses a personal theme and also some personal extensions.

I have updated core_flag to change web_unsecure_url and web_secure_url, and have updated local.xml and config.xml in /app/etc.
I also cleared the image cache, and this is where the problem seems to start.

Here is what the store looks like right now: 184.170.141.77. As you can see, a part of the page loads up correctly, but not the blocks and the the images in the media folder, and it seems like once the theme tries to insert an  tag in the page, everything stops loading. All the images load up perfectly in the backend though.

I looked at the apache error log, nothing comes up. I also tried disabling cache, this does not change anything. I have also tried to desactivate all the products and reactivate them, this does nothing also.

Looking at the script panel in firebug, this is what I find:

```
   <div class="listing-type-list catalog-listing">
   <div class="listing-item">
   <div class="product-image">
   <a href="http://184.170.141.77/graines-exotiques/graines-abutilon-megapotamicum-graines-drapeau-belge.html" title="">
    <img src="
```

The page seems to stop loading everything once it encounters what would be the link for the image.  Looking in the theme list file list.phtml, this is where the problem seems to be:

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135, 135); ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>" />
```

Yet this is the exact same thing as in the default folder.

I have checked the permissions on the folders, everything seems correct. I have then changed the src for :

```
<?php echo $_product->getSmallImage(); ?>
```

While this does not load any images, at least all items appear on the page. I have also tried with this line:

```
Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(135,135)
```

But I get the same result as with the original code.

Does anyone know what could be the cause of this problem?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

although this questions is nearly one year old, I want to answer it.

As I had the same problem, I found out that php5-gd was not installed on the new server.

So the quick and easy solution is eg. for Debian systems:

```
apt-get install php5-gd
```

For CentOS/Fedora/Redhat systems:

```
yum install php-gd
```

Comment: Good one, that had been bugging me for days!

Comment: Yep this is totally the correct answer. You saved my life Sven. sudo apt-get install php5-gd
sudo apachectl restart and I was done!

Comment: Spent a full day dealing with this. Swore that PHP logging was broken, couldn't find exceptions anywhere, messed with permissions all day, thought that I had an issue with FastCGI. Turns out my sysadmin neglected to bother with `php-gd`